# Pandas .sort_values() function returning data frame with scattered values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pandas to load a short_desc.csv with the following columns: ["report_id", "when","what"]

with

```py
#read csv
shortDesc = pd.read_csv('short_desc.csv') 

#get all numerical and nonnull values
shortDesc = shortDesc[shortDesc['report_id'].str.isdigit().notnull()]

#convert 'when' from UNIX timestamp to datetime
shortDesc['when'] = pd.to_datetime(shortDesc['when'],unit='s')
```

which results in the following:

[image: short descript results]

I'm trying to remove rows that have duplicate 'report_id's by sorting by
date and getting the newest date where that 'report_id' is present with the following:

```py
shortDesc = shortDesc.sort_values(by='when').drop_duplicates(['report_id'], keep='last')
```

the problem is that when I use .sort_values() in this particular dataframe the values of 'what' come out scattered across all columns, and the 'report_id' values disappear:

```py
shortDesc = shortDesc.sort_values(by=['when'], inplace=False)
```

[image: scatter results]

I'm not sure why this is happening in this particular instance since I was able to achieve the correct results by another dataframe with the same shape and using the same code (P.S it's not a mistake, I dropped the 'what' column in the second pic):

similar shape dataframe
[image: similar dataframe]

desired results example with similar shape DF
[image: similar data frame desired results]

Comment: It's not really "scattered across all columns", is it?  It's just that `what` and `report_id` have traded places.  Is that really all of the code?

Comment: @TimRoberts the code that affects what is being loaded from "short_desc.csv", yes. Also, the date is being changed, and in some rows the values of what is in the "reported_id" column and in others they're in the "what" column. I'm baffled as to what is happening.

Comment: Can you provide data that reproduces this problem?

Comment: @Frodnar & @Time Roberts , I figured out what was throwing .sort_values() function off. There was  a string value in report_id, which was not being checked for in 
```shortDesc[shortDesc['report_id'].str.isdigit().notnull()]``` I'm assuming since it probably first check if it was a digit, then it was changed if it was a number, I moved both checks to two lines, and that fixed it. I'm still confused as to why a string value in 'report_id' was affecting .sort_values(by="when") when report_id should not have had anything to do with the sort.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that:

```py
#get all numerical and nonnull values
shortDesc = shortDesc[shortDesc['report_id'].str.isdigit().notnull()]
```

was only checking if a value was not null and probably overwriting the str.isdigit() check, which caused the field "report_id" to not drop nonnumeric values. I changed this to two separate lines

```py
shortDesc = shortDesc[shortDesc['report_id'].notnull()]
shortDesc = shortDesc[shortDesc['report_id'].str.isnumeric()]
```

which allowed

```py
shortDesc.sort_values(by='when', inplace=True)
```

to work as intended, I am still confused as to why .sort_values(by="when") was affected by the column "report_id". So if anyone knows please enlighten me.